# C# 2D string list/array. Grouping together items that are associated with a certain name and assigning them to that name in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, listbox

I am trying to figure out the best approach to go about solving this "listArray-assignment" problem. I am opening a txt file (examples of lines in file provided below) and reading it with File.ReadAllLines. From there, I add all of the actors to listBox1 (while avoiding the addition of duplicate names).

That's the easy part; Here's the kicker: the txt file has movies associated with the actors. These movies must appear in listBox2 when the actor in these movies is selected in listBox1. Many actors, indeed, have multiple movies (refer to so I want to set up a 2D array that stores the first list as the actor list and the second list as the movie list, where the movies are assigned to their respective actors.

To clarify, if "John" has the movies "a" "b" and "c" then John should be an element in list 1. List 2 (corresponding with "John") should be assigned to values a, b, and c (since they are John's movies).

My two ideas were 1) a List and 2) a List> but my attempts to fill these lists were ineffective.

If you understand how to solve this, I would greatly appreciate you weighing in:)

Let me know if either of my approaches would be effective (and how to implement them) or if I need to change my approach entirely. Thank you!!

```
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string[]> map_data = new List<string[]>();  // idea1
        List<List<string>> jake = new List<List<string>>(); // idea2

        var logFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\Users\\jake\\Desktop\\movies.txt"); // absolute path -- CHANGE LATER
        var logList = new List<string>(logFile);    // reads lines and puts them in an array

        for (int i = 0; i < logList.Count; i++)
        {
            string j = logList[i].ToString();   // takes given element of list and casts to string
            string[] parts = j.Split(',');  // splits text file lines into [actor],[movie]
            string p1 = parts[0];   // p1 = actor
            string p2 = parts[1];   // p2 = movie
            if (listBox1.Items.Contains(p1))    // if actor already inserted
            {   
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(p1); // adds person to listbox if not already added (dups exist)
            }
        }
```

First 5 Lines of txt File (actor,movie):

Leslie Howard,Pygmalion

Wendy Hiller,Pygmalion

Ray Milland,French Without Tears

Michael Redgrave,The Importance of Being Earnest

Ray Milland,The Importance of Being Earnest  // 2nd movie for Ray Milland

Comment: why don't you create either a `Dictionary` or create a class that represents the structure of the text file I think it would be much easier to manage / parse / store the data

Comment: Good idea. I'll see if I can throw something together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this, I'd create a dataset with two datatables (movies, actors) and a datatelation between them such that the movies table actorid column was keyed to the actors table id column. Reason being that datatables can be connected directly to listboxes via a bindingsource, and then changing the selected item in one list automatically refines the other list (when the second list bindingsource has its datasource set to the datarelation

This is essentially the approach method man discusses when he says create a custom class; the dataset designer creates tables are custom classes in their own right

This is however, all likely a bit involved. You can probably achieve a simpler solution in a bit more of a manual sense- establish two Dictionary> objects to relate actors to movies and vice versa. Populate the dictionaries like this (rename your p1 and p2 variables to something more sensible):

```
actorsToMovies[actor].Add(movie);
moviesToActors[movie].Add(actor);
```

Note: the first time you go to add a particular key, it won't exist, so best to make your addition code work like:

```
if(!actorsToMovies.ContainsKey(actor))
  actorsToMovies[actor] = new List<string>();
actorsToMovies[actor].Add(movie);
```

now fill your actors list box with the contents of the `actorsToMovie.Keys` - a deduped list of actor names

Now attach an event handler to the actor list box selected index changed event. You do this by goin to the visual designer for the form, left click the list box, in the properties grid in the right, click the lighting bolt tab to see alll the events. Find the SelectedIndexChanged one and double click in the empty space next to it. The view will switch to code, and you're tasked with writing the code for the event handler. The event handler code should:

1. Clear the movies list box, with `moviesListbox.Items.Clear()`
2. Get the currently selected actor from the actors list box, `var actor = actorsListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`
3. Now loop through all the movies in the list retrieved from actorsToMovies[actor], adding them to the list box. You can alternatively add a range:`moviesListbox.Items.AddRange(actorsToMovies[actor]);`

Of course, this could have been done with a single dictionary, but using two allows you to easily list the other actors of any given movie, for example

Comment: Ok. I created a dictionary and assigned each "actor a" to the movies "b" "c" and "d" (for example). Thank you! I have a question though. In listBox2, how do I populate the box with the movies of the actor selected? For example, I want to make it so that if Actor A in listbox1 is selected, Actor A's movies should be displayed in listbox2. Furthermore, if Actor B is selected, Actor B's movies should be displayed in listbox2. How can I program the class to change lists as a new actor is selected?

Comment: That's the part of the answer starting with "now attach an" ... I'll edit some more steps in to assist